# IF em PHP não funciona

Tags: php

Se eu estiver na página teste/1, ele adicione a classe `logoPrincipalHosp` na **li** se não a classe `logoPrincipalElev`.

Meu PHP:

```
<li <?php if (preg_match('/teste\/1/')) echo 'class="logoPrincipalHosp"';
else (preg_match('/teste\/2/')) echo 'class="logoPrincipalElev"';
?>>
```

Porém, não está funcionando

Comment: Não devia ser `elseif` em vez de `else`?

Comment: Você está esquecendo um parâmetro no `preg_match` =).
[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @Sergio era isso cara, que falta de atenção minha, valeu! :D

Comment: @Oeslei na verdade eu só esqueci de colocar o parâmetro aqui, no meu código ele já está. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiseres juntar outra condição a ser verificada no `else`, então tens de usar `elseif`.